# Is there any way, using ui-router, to bind variables from controller into the template without using $scope?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-ui-router, ng-controller

My $stateProvider:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: "/home",
            views: {
                "header": {templateUrl: "templates/header.html"},
                "footer": {
                    templateUrl  : "templates/footer.html",
                    controllerAs : "footerCtrl",
                    controller   : function($scope){
                        footerCtrl($scope);
                    }
                }
            }
        })

function footerCtrl($scope){
    console.log($scope);
    $scope.var1 = "Fulvio";
    this.var2 = "Cosco";
}
```

template Html:

```
<div>
    {{var1}}
    {{footerCtrl.var2}}
</div>
```

If I try to write ng-controller="footerCtrl" into the DIV no data-binding and I get an error, whereas if I don't write it no errors and no data-binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
function footerCtrl() {
    this.var1 = "Fulvio";
    this.var2 = "Cosco";
    console.log(this);
}

// Declare the controller
yourAngularModule.controller('footerCtrl', footerCtrl);

$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        views: {
            "header": {templateUrl: "templates/header.html"},
            "footer": {
                templateUrl  : "templates/footer.html",
                controllerAs : "footer", // The controller alias
                controller   : "footerCtrl",
            }
        }
    })
```

Use it like this:

```
// templates/footer.html
<div>
    {{footer.var1}}
    {{footer.var2}}
</div>
```

Like this you have a real [`controllerAs`](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) syntax.

Comment: What such a stupid I am... ahah, I forgot tu define "yourAngularModule.controller('footerCtrl', footerCtrl);"

Thanks.